# How do I query the database without having to send a GET/POST request

Tags: jquery, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a web application using node/express and mongoose. The app has a database of Products and Customers - I am trying to add the functionality for placing an Order. The app is being used by employees, taking Orders for Customers.

I am trying to create an "Add Order" page where the employee enters in Customer information and adds Products one by one as the Customer says what they want. As the employee is adding "Line-items", I want him/her to be able to search for an existing Product in Products collection.

Furthermore, the Customers have a unique Customer Number that they are given to use in the future. If a Customer calls as gives their Customer Number to us, I want to be able to enter that into this page and have their information populate the fields.

How can I achieve these functionalities? I don't want to have to load the entire Products and Customer collections on the "Add Order" GET, as that is definitely not scalable. I imagine there must be a way to query the database from within the web page, receive data, and manipulate/populate that data using jQuery. A POST request and page refresh is not what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

> I want him/her to be able to search for an existing Product in
> Products collection.

If you know that the products collection will not change, you don't need DB and you can attach/load a JS file with all the products( the file can load a  JSON and then you must to use JSON.parse() )
If you know that the products may change, you need to query at least one time( when the page is loading) and store the data , but if some data change, you will need to query over HTTP request to get the last version. NOT RECOMMENDED

> How can I achieve these functionalities? I don't want to have to load
> the entire Products and Customer collections on the "Add Order" GET,
> as that is definitely not scalable. I imagine there must be a way to
> query the database from within the web page, receive data, and
> manipulate/populate that data using jQuery. A POST request and page
> refresh is not what I'm after.

Some points:
1)Database let you scale you app. Scaling with the first solution I gave you is impossible because if there is a change you wont see it in the next time the app is on.
2)You don't have to query all the time for all the products or all the costumer info stored in the DB. It's all about requirements.
3) jQuery help to you get more with less code, don't let you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Your response sparked my realization that my Products are not going to change after the page loads, so I just need to load the entire Products collection into the  background on the initial page load. Can access and do text searches later. Cheers.

Comment: I hope I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: AJAX. I didn't know what that was. Now I know.